# JQuery plugin gives error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am newbie to JQuery. I have a table. I want to apply two plugins in my table. I use Tablesorter and tablescroll plugins.

Javascript files that I've included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablescroll.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I include the below given code in head section of my HTML, nothing works.
And when I include it at the end of the file, just after the closing body tags, table scroll function works. Table sorting doesnot work at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($)

            {
                $('#showconnections').tableScroll({height:500});

                $('#showconnections').tablesorter();

            });

        </script>
```

I checked in the console, following error is given:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My table tag is simple.

```
<table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped tablesorter" border="1">

    <thead>
         <tr>

                <th rowspan="2">city id</th>
                <th rowspan="2">state name</th>
              <th rowspan="2">cityname</th>
                <th rowspan="2">state code</th>
                <th rowspan="2">zip code</th>
           </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
<tr>


            <td>fdfd</td>
            <td>ddffd</td>
            <td>dffd</td>
            <td>dfdf</td>
            <td>fgfd</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

NB: structure of the table tag is given above. data is dummy. my table contains multiple rows.

Comment: You are including jQuery twice - once in `jquery-latest.js` and once from the google CDN. I'd suggest you remove one of them and ensure jQuery is always the first script included in the page.

Comment: I tried that. Table sorting doesnot work. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  @Rory McCrossan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please add your comment as an answer, I'll upvote it! @TheJoker `js/jquery-latest.js` and `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` are both copies of jQuery. Remove ONE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LFBmL/2/

I have created fiddle for you.please look into it.
The JavaScript code must be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
        $('#myTable').tableScroll({height:300});
    } 
); 
</script>
```

Note:

- "$('#showconnections')" which element has id"showconnections" ,if you meant your table then it must be "myTable"
- Both your plugins "TableScroll" & "Table Sorted" combined ,dont go well with UI .

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/LFBmL/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/LFBmL/3/)Try This Fiddle. You could use both ,u have to take care of some minor UI fixes,for instance  Up and down arrows for sorting willbe missing.Hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Include your `jQuery` main library at first

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablescroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that. Table sorting doesnot work. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function @Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

Load Jquery plugin on the top of the head.

Comment: I tried that. Table sorting doesnot work. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function @pratik nagariya

Comment: could you please create jsfiddle link.